# Run sql function from EXISTS query using postgres CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

In a postgres sql function I want to run `function_update` only if the CTE returns any rows. This query works for that.

```
with common_table as (select 1 where true) select function_update('value') from common_table
```

But if I also want to return whether `function_update` updated any rows, then it doesn't work. The function does return `true` or `false` correctly depending whether CTE returned any rows or not, but `function_update` doesn't seem to run.

```
with common_table as (select 1 where true) select exists(select function_update('value') from common_table)
```

`function_update` is just something simple like `update mytable set column1 = 'changed' where column2 = arg_value`. `mytable` gets updated when I run the first query above but not the second. Why isn't this working as expected, what do I need to change?

Comment: What does `function_update()` return?

Comment: It's a function with `returns void`. Doesn't return anything just updates a row.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't this working as expected

Exists check the existence and query optimizer does not have to execute the function. Following example show that we could expect an division by 0 error:

```
select 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1/0);
-- 1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=459533273a9b01c7c70e64ad6c087206)**

---

> what do I need to change?

One way is to force materialization:

```
select 1 WHERE EXISTS (WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED (SELECT 1/0) SELECT * FROM cte)
-- division by 0
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6347cfdf072e7afc43a3a5c145c108a5)**

Comment: How can I get the desired effect of updating if CTE exists?